# Consulta MySQL com RAND

Tags: mysql

Existe alguma forma de eu trazer registros do MySQL, onde o campo (por exemplo) is_new seja = 1, mas quando não existir registros com o campos is_new = 1, quero que na consulta ele faça um ORDER BY rand(), é possível?

Na prática, cada vez que faço um select, quero trazer 5 clientes, usando o order by rand, mas, quando tiver registros novos (e para isso o campo is_new, da tabela cliente recebe 1) quero que ele traga 5 desses ultimos registros, assim quando os registros forem exibidos a flag dele muda para 0 e na próxima consulta, vem apenas do rand

Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Com essa *query* ele pega 5 registros, priorizando sempre os `is_new`:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela ORDER BY is_new != 1, RAND() LIMIT 5
```

- Quando o `is_new` for 1, a expressão `is_new != 1` retornará `false`, deixando o registro em primeiro lugar.
- **Importante:** lembre-se que o `RAND` é aplicado ao set todo do where ANTES do limit, essa solução não é adequada para situações e que você tem muitos ítens e vai pegar poucos - nestes casos deve preferir um `COUNT` seguido de um rand para pegar um aleatório, e em seguida fazer um `SELECT ... LIMIT sorteado, 1`